# dompdf: white margin on A4 page

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I am using dompdf (a PHP library) to create a PDF page and I have a problem to set proper dimensions. When I use CSS property:

```css
@page {
    size: 21cm 29.7cm; 
}
```

… and for example I want to have the upper part of the page in red color, the PDF file is OK, but after print I got white margin. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi nolbadi111, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you explain in a little more detail what is going wrong with the printing? For example, is it possible to [edit] the question to include images of the pdf output and print output, for comparison?

Comment: After printing it to physical paper? In that case, the problem may be caused by the actual printer layout settings, which add to the visible part of the PDF.

Answer (score 7):

You've set the size of the page, but not the content boundaries. If you don't want any border on the page you have to set the page margins to 0.

```
@page {
  size: 21cm 29.7cm;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This removes the margin around the body, but it also means that your content will bump up against the page edge. If you want the body content to having some spacing from the edge give it some padding.

```
body {
  padding: .5in;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use width and height, but size was what worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

nolbadi111:

Did you set the right paper size, with setPaper() function?

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

Reference: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: but I am not sure it's work, because when I type "A3" or "portrait" I got the same results...

Comment: ok, I remove "page" propperty in css and now "setPaper" function works, but now I hava big margin also in pdf file.

Comment: dompdf generates margins according to its own standards. But you can change this behavior in css for your html file.

Add the following rule to css:
@page {
            margin-top: 0.3em;
            margin-left: 0.6em;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was not with the domPDF, but with the printer settings. To acheive the goal you have to set borderless property.

btw. when you use

```
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
```

you don't need to set page size property in css (but it helps during creating page in html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@page { size: auto; size: A4 portrait; }
```

Comment: Code-only answer are discouraged. Could you add some explanation about this solution?